# Fork and Pipe problem - unlimited printing

Tags: c, pipe

After launching this code in int main():

```
int p[2];
char *argv[2];
argv[0] = "wc";
argv[1] = "0";
pipe(p);
if(fork() == 0) {
    close(0);
    dup(p[0]);
    close(p[0]);
    close(p[1]);
    execv("/bin/wc", argv);
} else {
    close(p[0]);
    write(p[1], "pls work finally jesus\n", 12);
    close(p[1]);
}
```

I end up with unlimited "> > > > > > > > > > > > > (...)" constantly printing in my terminal. How can i fix that?

Comment: Although it's not responsible for your problem, I strongly recommend using `dup2()` instead of `close()` + `dup()`.

Answer (score 3):

Per [the POSIX `execv()` documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html) (bolding mine):

> `int execv(const char *path, char *const argv[]);`
>
> ...
>
> The argument `argv` is an array of character pointers to null-terminated
>   strings. **The application shall ensure that the last member of this
>   array is a null pointer.** ...

This does not meet those conditions:

```
char *argv[2];
argv[0] = "wc";
argv[1] = "0";
```

`"0"` is not a "null pointer".  You're assigning the address of a string literal that contains the string `"0"` to `argv[1]`.  Since the last member of the array isn't a "null pointer", you're invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 
This was a small example as I'm building my own shell and implementing pipes is my last thing to do. Im doing them recursivelly.


In this small example chaning argv[1] = NULL; should fix the problem then? Tried it and it's still weird. 

Altough in the main program I already have functioning pipe but with "execvp(args[0], args)" instead and im getting the same problem. Where:

char ** args, cpy[1000];  
   
args = calloc((spacecount)+2, sizeof(char *));  
for(c = 0; c < spacecount + 1; c++){  
args[c] = calloc(strlen(in[i])+10, sizeof(char));  
}